# App Tracking Transparency doesn't show dialogue bbox

Tags: ios, swift

I've tried the solutions in other related questions but none of the answers work for me.

I've got App Tracking Transparency set up but for some reason, the dialogue box for it never shows on screen. This is the code I'm using:

```
    func appTrackingAuthorisation() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization { status in
                switch status {
                case .authorized:
                    print("Enable tracking")
                case .denied:
                    print("Deny tracking")
                case .restricted:
                    print("Restrict (denied) tracking")
                default:
                    print("Not determined")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In my `viewDidLoad()` is where I'm calling the function:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        appTrackingAuthorisation()
        checkLocationServices()
    }
```

I also have a location permission dialogue box show and I'm not sure if that being there is causing the ATT to not show up. I've tried putting it in AppDelegate in `func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication)` as that's what Apple recommends but it still doesn't work. NSUserTrackingUsageDescription in Info.plist is also set. Allow apps to ask for tracking is also enabled.

Comment: I think you are showing location and ATT popup together that's why it is creating issue can you try by commenting out the checkLocationServices function and run App after that.

Comment: @HammerClass  Yep, I think that is the problem, I added DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter to help the issue but that didn't really do anything. Anything else I can do?

Comment: I don't know Swift. But be sure to test ATT on devices with ios 14+. If you want you can also send a request for technical help to Apple Developer support (if you have an account and have registered to publish apps, in the support section you should find the possibility to request free technical help to write code (I think you have two free requests every year) (this from what I remember))